# How to return current value of ng-model for requirement conditional

Tags: angularjs

I have a select box that is populated using ng-options, and I need to conditionally change the requirement of certain fields based on what is selected in the select box. My function to check if the value is in an array:

```
  $scope.getBTypeSelected = function () {
    return $scope.formData.businessType;
  };
  // Business Type conditionals
  $scope.isRequired = function() {
    var notRequired = ['2', '5', '6', '7', '12', '80'];
    if ($.inArray($scope.getBTypeSelected(), notRequired) == -1) {
      return false;
    }else {
      return true;
    }
  };
```

I've tried $watch-ing the scope variable for changes and updating it, and I've tried retrieving the current value via a function to no avail so far.

I understand that the conditionals are getting the initial value of that variable, but I don't understand why I am unable to update it.

Here is a plunker demonstrating my issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/FKFvDu2RMjDKRva6JYwi?p=preview

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you notice that your array contain strings? With $scope.getBTypeSelected().toString() this will work.

Comment: I did not. wow. such a simple fix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing strings to integers. Your array contains strings, but your selected item is an integer, so `inArray` is always returning false. I changed the array to integers and its working as intended.

```
var notRequired = [2, 5, 6, 7, 12, 80];
```